# PIVOT & UNPIVOT in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not at all familiar with PIVOT & UNPIVOT. Could anyone help me making this transpose. I've data like this:

```
No.     Date    Type    Amount  Amount_R
1234    15-Nov   A         0     0
1234    15-Nov   B         0     0
1234    15-Nov   C        10     10
5678    15-Nov   B         5     0
```

I need data like this:

```
No.      Date    A   B   C   C_R
1234    15-Nov   0   0   10  100
5678    15-Nov   0   5   0    0
```

Could any please help me making the query.

Comment: C_R is a new column. Explain what it is.

Comment: Check out this [Documentation](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506) for more information. Try to make a query and if an issue comes post it here and we will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your table to be like:

```
    create table tab1 (col1 NUMBER(10), col2 DATE, col3 VARCHAR2(2), amt NUMBER(10), amt_r NUMBER(10));
```

Something of the following kind may help:

```
    SELECT * FROM
          (SELECT col1, col2, col3,
                  amt,
                  amt_r
             FROM tab1)
            PIVOT (MAX(NVL(amt, 0))
              FOR col3 IN ('A',
                           'B',
                           'C'));
```

Also there are a lot of details in your question missing. Please elaborate more.
Read about Pivot/Unpivot on Internet too.
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify how to calculate the value for C_R column in the output. If you simply need the value to be displayed you can use the following query.

```
SELECT "No.","Date",NVL(A,0),NVL(A_R,0),NVL(B,0),NVL(B_R,0),NVL(C,0),NVL(C_R,0)
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT "No.","Date","Type","Amount","Amount_R"
FROM t)
PIVOT (MAX("Amount"),MAX("Amount_R") as "R" FOR "Type" IN ('A' as A,'B' as B,'C' as C)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT "No.",
       "Date",
       COALESCE( a, 0 ) AS a,
       COALESCE( b, 0 ) AS b,
       COALESCE( c, 0 ) AS c,
       COALESCE( c * amount_r, 0 ) AS c_r
FROM   table_name
PIVOT  ( SUM( amount ) FOR Type IN ( 'A' AS A, 'B' AS B, 'C' AS C ) );
```